# is it possible to execute nightwatch tests using/within another tool like playright or puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer, nightwatch.js, webdriver-io, playwright

I have a bunch of Nightwatch tests. Nightwatch is not getting updates as fast as other JS tools in the market. I don't want to recreate the tests again just so I can make a switch to for example playwright. Is it possible to run nightwatch tests with anothert ool?

Comment: No, it's not possible

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is NOT possible to do that currently.

But would be interested to know what is your case in getting this done. If you are looking to run Nightwatch tests using cucumber, jest, etc.., you can try [Nightwatch-API](https://nightwatch-api.netlify.app/)